# Bootstrap big margin below help-block class

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am making this simple form using bootstrap but there seems to be a big margin below the `.help-block` class. How can I remove it without affecting the responsiveness or am I doing something wrong?

```css
.user-help {
  background: red;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
 }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class='container'>
<form class='form-horizontal'>
    <div class='form-group'>
       <input id='fname' type='text' class='form-control' placeholder='First Name'>
       <div class='help-block user-help'>First name missing</div>
    </div>
    <div class='form-group'>
        <button type='submit' class='btn btn-primary btn-block'>Sign Up</button>
    </div>
</form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Apply `margin-bottom: 0;` to `.user-help` and `.form-group` specifying their parent div class.

```css
.form-group .user-help {
  background: red;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.form-horizontal .form-group {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class='container'>
  <form class='form-horizontal'>
    <div class='form-group'>
      <input id='fname' type='text' class='form-control' placeholder='First Name'>
      <div class='help-block user-help'>First name missing</div>
    </div>
    <div class='form-group'>
      <button type='submit' class='btn btn-primary btn-block'>Sign Up</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A big margin below the .help-block class, There are two reasons:

1. .form-group has style with margin-bottom: 15px;
2. .help-block has style with margin-bottom: 10px;

You can change or remove margin-bottom value of either the first .form-group class or .help-block class.